# Incrontab does not execute command

Tags: inotify, incron

When I use incrontab out of the box, I mean no changes,
I get no result, as if the command was not executed.

my incron line is :
`/crrae IN_CREATE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN_MOVED_TO /usr/bin/unix2dos $#`

the log give information as if everything was ok but no actually

the strace generated is: `incrontab_trace_0.txt`

```
 0.000000 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 3, -1) = 1 ([{fd=8, revents=POLLIN}])
17.616276 read(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0000\0\0\0ExportSageJDE_CO"..., 32768) = 64
 0.000145 stat64("/crrae", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
 0.000147 time(NULL)                = 1399228077
 0.000056 stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=156, ...}) = 0
 0.000089 stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=156, ...}) = 0
 0.000082 stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=156, ...}) = 0
 0.000096 send(3, "<78>May  4 18:27:57 incrond[3183"..., 108, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 108
 0.000104 clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb7f60718) = 31838
 0.000816 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 3, -1) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
 0.000834 --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
 0.000033 read(4, 0x8069c40, 32)    = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
 0.000057 write(5, "X", 1)          = 1
 0.000056 sigreturn()               = ? (mask now [])
 0.000072 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 3, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
 0.000068 read(4, "X", 1)           = 1
 0.000054 read(4, 0xbfd22dd9, 1)    = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
 0.000057 waitpid(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 1}], WNOHANG) = 31838
 0.000060 waitpid(-1, 0xbfd22dd4, WNOHANG) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
 0.000051 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 3, -1) = 1 ([{fd=8, revents=POLLIN}])
 0.009198 read(8, "\1\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0000\0\0\0ExportSageJDE_CO"..., 32768) = 64
 0.000074 stat64("/crrae", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
 0.000118 time(NULL)                = 1399228077
 0.000057 stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=156, ...}) = 0
 0.000084 stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=156, ...}) = 0
 0.000082 stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=156, ...}) = 0
 0.000090 send(3, "<78>May  4 18:27:57 incrond[3183"..., 108, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 108
 0.000065 clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb7f60718) = 31839
 0.000614 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 3, -1) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
 0.000832 --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
 0.000026 read(4, 0x8069c40, 32)    = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
 0.000055 write(5, "X", 1)          = 1
 0.000054 sigreturn()               = ? (mask now [])
 0.000071 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 3, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
 0.000067 read(4, "X", 1)           = 1
 0.000053 read(4, 0xbfd22dd9, 1)    = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
 0.000051 waitpid(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 1}], WNOHANG) = 31839
 0.000058 waitpid(-1, 0xbfd22dd4, WNOHANG) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
 0.000050 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 3, -1 <unfinished ...>
```

When I change my incron to:

```
/crrae IN_CREATE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN_MOVED_TO /usr/bin/unix2dos /crrae/$#
```

or

```
/crrae IN_CREATE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN_MOVED_TO /usr/bin/unix2dos $@/$#
```

the log gives me this:

```
May  4 18:15:10 srvovs incrond[20859]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/unix2dos /crrae/u2dtmpPbqoFd)
May  4 18:15:10 srvovs incrond[20859]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/unix2dos /crrae/u2dtmpN2Odxf)
May  4 18:15:10 srvovs incrond[20859]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/unix2dos /crrae/u2dtmpN2Odxf)
```

multiple times, the `incron.conf` has not been modified. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Running a command (`unix2dos`) that writes to and closes a file based on a `CLOSE_WRITE` event is what is known as a "loop".  `incrontab` has protections against looping built in.

Comment: I think you want just the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` with a pattern that excludes the `tmp` files used by `unix2dos`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try capturing what, when and why incron is doing stuff.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "[$( date )] $*" >>/tmp/myincronlog
```

and add $% to the incrontab arguments.

Given that you are only providing a single argument to your command implies that it is modifying the file in place. The means that the incron action will create incron events. While incrond will attempt to handle such instances but only if you tell it with IN_NO_LOOP. But its better to avoid the issue arising by not modifying the target file in an incron action is a way which would trigger incron.